# How can I correctly type a dictionary whose members' shape I don't know ahead of time?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Assume I had this JS object for my TS dictionary shape:

```js
const myItems = {
  itemOne: {
    id: 'itemOne'
  },
  itemTwo: {
    id: 'itemTwo',
    meta: []
  }
}
```

In vanilla JS, one can simply append, say, `itemThree`, and it'll get added. However, when creating the equivalent of this in TS, [using code jcalz provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSNgFsA8BlOUTAOwBMBnOAJWAGNpSdyYoBLYgcwBo4BDYxAD5BcALxwA3nFakAXHGZtOAbjgBfOADI4eZQFgAUIdCRYCZKgzZyOACqEQJCtToMcAa2CIIAMzi2eGnooRkV2bj4BYRFxKQBtAGlpYjhPbz9bAF15K1xbRMyRNX0jA3piZmlMLEpxOwcnSiC3NN9-QNcQphZwnn4hYQAKVnl7bVybW0EAShzqyZiRVhLDcsqsRAmxKutBiUM4Q52sAHliYHl9gyOb6Tk4AHJWarPgB4OjtS4Pw%20fsWwA7hBLj9bjJ5E9qoCIA9vtdbocsMAYLx5HFMqC1IY1NNDIYAPQAKjga3gGwmc2sOCuNz%20p3OIPhCPBCh6KkxJVpUKBjIRv3uYXZTNuSJR8nOADdgFB0ZzPiU1CJCfjDEA), all we get is an object, which, again, in TS, cannot change.

My needs are:

1. Being able to do CRUD operations on the dictionary.
2. Somehow (my initial thought was generics) pass information about the member-to-be-inserted's shape to `myItems` -
3. Be able to use that information to get typings.

I am not sure how to achieve this, and I must say that I'm further confused by the fact that TS can't inherently detect the shape of a dictionary's members. If I [create a dictionary](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwJJQKZwgLhgbxgbQEswATVAD22gCdiBzAXWz0JKqlrDpgF8YAyGACVUoaiQA8NegBoYAQzAIAfHwC8uHgG4AsACh9iFOgj4A5ITRwA8mFRmGMDTn0w3MVtgtXb9ma-c4VCh5bHwGfR59Q2QrU290ABUAdxAHJ1wAt08YBLgUtP89KIM9IzjzS3RfBwA6VgyzRNRoM11S0EhYKps7JBIM8pNKnzs61nagA), typings are all over the place, and TS doesn't really help me. How can I make TS aware of the supposedly complex shape of the members of `myItems`?

Comment: @jcalz Sure, just updated with an example. Edit: **Yea!** Your example works, but I don't quite understand the TS behind it. Would appreciate a quick explanation, at least in terms of theory. **The "need a function for this" part is definitely confusing, as I was assuming typing like this shouldn't be this hard to achieve.**

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBVMVN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know if you "need a function for this" or not. I don't know what your use case is apart from having an object literal. How did you want to assign it to a variable?  How would you want to assign a single `Item<S>` to a variable?  Do you specify `S` or do expect it to be inferred?

Comment: @jcalz It does solve it, yea. Just wondering why it's not straight-forward (to me).

Comment: @jcalz The other thing that makes this a bit confusing is that this *isn't really an object*. I can't add to `myItems` as I normally would with an object.

Comment: I would love to write up an answer but your comments keep giving me pause. I'd like to know I'm on the same page as you (or at least in the same book) before I spend effort on the answer (if you see my other answers you'll know they are, uh, not short).  What do you mean by "this isn't really an object"?  It sure looks like an object to me.  What does "add to `myItems`" mean?  Does it mean you're adding properties or something?  I'd need to see a [mre] that demonstrates your problem or confusion; a verbal description alone isn't helping me.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for being so involved. Not sure how we ended up at this confusion, but let's just use [link](http://tsplay.dev/NBVLxN) . So, with an object, I can just simply add an item to it, just like it, but in this case, I can't. I understand why it's doing it, but not sure how to fix it, hence why I asked about why "the object is being created (populated?) by a function".

Comment: Please show me  "I can just simply add an item to it" in some other case.  Are you talking about TypeScript?  If so, please show me the code.

Comment: @jcalz [link](https://tsplay.dev/mbaL9N) line 32. Just a basic object. With your original answer, I can't do any operations on `myItems`. Say, I wanted to add another member from an outside, remote place, yea? Well, I can't do that.

Comment: What you're calling an "object" is more specific type than an object, you are apparently referring to a  *dictionary* with an index signature like `Record<string, X>` so you can add any key you want.  By default an object type in TypeScript does not act this way; an object of type `{a: string}` will not accept extra properties. So could you [edit] the question to refer to a *dictionary*, possibly using the term [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and explain how you need to add new properties to the object *after* it has a type?

Comment: And once you do that, this doesn't seem possible.  You can write `type Items = Record<string, Item<Record<string, any>>>;`, but then you lose the specific information about each property.  Presumably you want `myItems.item3 = {id: "item3", a: "abc"}` to remember that `item3` has an `a` property.  This has little to do with generics.  Anyway I'll wait to see if the question gets [edit]ed to something I can understand an answer.  If so I'll engage further. If not, good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Ok, I wasn't aware of the terminology here. So, with TS, a "dynamic object" is actually a *dictionary*. When I don't know the shape of the dictionary, I will need an *index signature*. Ok, really good to have the terminology correct. I guess the `Item` signature becomes `export type Item<S extends Record<string, any>> = { [index: string]: { id: string; } & S; }` then, but not sure how to take it from there. **Anyways, edited the question to correctly represent what I'm trying to do.**

Comment: Does something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3ERkw) work for you where you can add an item to an object of items using an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)?

Comment: @jcalz Sure, this covers all my needs (if you create an answer with just this, I will approve, as it answers the question), **but why is it so complicated?** One would think that defining a dictionary, and doing CRUD on it would be a walk in the park. You wrote `addItem`, sure, but there's no way I can even come close to that complexity of writing, so, I wouldn't be able to write `remove/update/etc.` myself. I guess there must be a library, but still - why is it so complex? Anyways, thanks a lot for clarifying things. I've learned so much.

Comment: You can’t write `remove` actually, and if `update` changes the *type* of the property then you can’t write that either. Types are really meant to represent invariants, not things that change arbitrarily over time. If you want to do that then you will find TS much more annoying than plain JS.  Ideally you should decide in advance what types things are going to be and then keep them that way.  But it requires a different mindset from the anything-goes freedom of JS.  So I could write up an answer here if you want but maybe the answer is that TS isn’t meeting your needs.

Comment: @jcalz That's actually pretty limiting. How do people create dictionaries that need to be updated all the time, and also get correct typings? As for the answers, well, it's up to you. The first thought was that it'd be *just noise*, but perhaps it'd help others understand that a TS *dictionary* isn't the same as a JS *object*, in very meaningful ways. Up to you :)

Comment: I think I’ll disengage. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz After 4-5 weeks of tribulations, my 200k LoC have been properly re-typed, and it's now a joy to add code. While I understand your standards for who you teach are high, your effort wasn't wasted, even if it appeared as such, as I have learned a lot in a short time. While it'll be years before I can come up with crazy-complex stuff, I'm 80% there. Your approach is correct. You should spend time only with those who "seem to have potential", but every now and then, the less fortunate ones make it. Thank you. Your influence has been invaluable.